# Can't get active admin to work on rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I went through the entire instruction and added

`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'` to my gemfile.

`bundle update` and `bundle install` went well with no errors, but when I load up my rails app and try to access `localhost:3000/admin` it says "could not get /admin route"

Am I missing some instructions? Do I have to manually map it?

Comment: take a look at http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html have you run the install rake command? Also for rails 4.1 make sure that you are on the master branch.

Comment: Do you see any routes to /admin if you run **rake routes**? If not, you may need to add the appropriate route to your config/routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to run `rails g active_admin:install` then `rake db:migrate`

start the server via `rails server` and you can visit `http://localhost:3000/admin` and log in as the default user:

- User: **admin@example.com**
- Password: **password**

also you can check their [docs](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/0-installation.md#setting-up-active-admin) on how to add the admin to existing `user` class